# What is the Mercurial equivalent of git checkout --patch (aka -p)?

Tags: mercurial

The Git command `git checkout --patch <commit>` allows you to interactively apply hunks from the diff between `HEAD` and `<commit>` to your worktree. In other words it allows you to prepare a commit that partially updates your repo to match a different commit.

Is there an equivalent in Mercurial?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this (and commit the changes) is:

```
hg revert -r <commit> --all
hg commit --interactive
# Deselect everything except what you want to keep in the interactive UI
hg revert --all
```

Comment: Slightly different approach instead of interactive commit would be to `hg revert` individual files/folders before the commit command. Just breaks up the task differently.